# Ranking table Rows based on shift timing

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i have a table called inputtable with columns equipment_id(int),telemetry_time(timestamp),i want to assign a row_number to the row from 8 am to 8am shift everyday.
the below is the sample data link,

**INPUT TABLE**

| equipment_id | telemetry_time |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 04:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 04:30:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 06:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 06:30:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 08:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 08:30:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 20:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 23:30:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-17 02:30:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-17 03:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-17 10:30:00 |

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**

| equipment_id | telemetry_time | Batch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 04:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 04:30:00 | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 06:00:00 | 3 |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 06:30:00 | 4 |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 08:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 08:30:00 | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 20:00:00 | 3 |
| 2 | 2022-06-16 23:30:00 | 4 |
| 2 | 2022-06-17 02:30:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 2022-06-17 03:00:00 | 6 |
| 2 | 2022-06-17 10:30:00 | 1 |

i have added desired output in the below link with table name desiredtable
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vhZbgTG8TcJ7SwqanoWEUL/4
please help me im new to SQL,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift your times back by eight hours to get the right date:

```
with date_shift as (
  select equipment_id, telemetry_time, 
         (telemetry_time - interval '8 hours')::date as tdate
    from inputtable
)
select equipment_id, telemetry_time, 
       row_number() over (partition by equipment_id, tdate
                              order by telemetry_time)
  from date_shift;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8ab009df1c93db262a7683d625197d56)*

Comment: i did the same, instead CTE i have used subquery,thanks for your answe

Comment: @udaygalidevara You are welcome.  The CTE is not strictly necessary.  I used it to make my answer more clear.  The query can be refactored by putting the date shift/trunc inside of the window definition as here:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4c0cebabbaf17aa7138cc909b7105649

Answer (score 0):

Try this query
**Note**: This query is not depend on the Equipment_id. and totally depend on the date and the time

```
   select  *,
   rank() OVER (PARTITION by  Shift_start_category::date, Shift_end_category::date ORDER BY telemetry_time  asc)
   from (
   select equipment_id, telemetry_time,
   case when(telemetry_time <=  telemetry_time::date + (' 8 hour')::interval) and  (telemetry_time >=  telemetry_time::date + (' 1920 minute')::interval)
   then  telemetry_time::date +  (' -24 hour')::interval 
   when(telemetry_time >=  telemetry_time::date + (' 8 hour')::interval) and  (telemetry_time <=  telemetry_time::date + (' 1920 minute')::interval)
    then  telemetry_time::date +  (' +24 hour')::interval 
   else telemetry_time::date + (' 8 hour')::interval end Shift_start_category,    
   case when(telemetry_time >=  telemetry_time::date + (' 8 hour')::interval) and  (telemetry_time <=  telemetry_time::date + (' 1920 minute')::interval)
   then  telemetry_time::date +  (' +24 hour')::interval 
   when(telemetry_time <=  telemetry_time::date + (' 8 hour')::interval) and  (telemetry_time >=  telemetry_time::date + (' 1920 minute')::interval)
    then  telemetry_time::date +  (' +24 hour')::interval 
   else telemetry_time::date + (' 8 hour')::interval end Shift_end_category
   from public.inputtable) A
  order by telemetry_time asc;
```

Shift_start_category and Shift_end_category fields only for display purposes .

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    *,
    dense_rank() over (partition by date,
    equipment_id
order by
        telemetry_time) as batch
from
    (
    select
        equipment_id,
        (telemetry_time - interval '8 hour')::date as date,
        telemetry_time
    from
        inputtable ) as t
order by
    equipment_id,
    telemetry_time
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).